# Check if a string contains an english word in NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js

What is the best way in NodeJS to create a function that returns true iff a string contains an english word longer than 3 letters?

The code will be placed in a lambda, so I'm looking for the most efficient solution. The best solution I've got so far is to use `dictionary-en` and iterate over every word calling `.includes(word)` on the source string, I was wondering if you can think of better approach to implement this.

Some examples of strings which should return true:

- y89nsdad**home**a98qwoi
- :_5678aSD.**boTTle**ads.
- yfugdnuagybdas**glasses**midwqihhniwqnhi

Some examples of strings which should return false:

- y89nsdadhasa98qwoi
- :_5678aSD.b0TTle4ds.
- yfugdnuagybdasmidwqihhniwqnhi

Comment: There are plenty of immediate efficiencies that come to mind over the brute force 'iterate every word'. ie. only iterate words that begin with a letter in the string, start with shorter words before longer ones, don't iterate over words longer than the longest span of letters, etc. etc. For short strings you can reverse the process and generate substrings of 4 or greater and test them against the dictionary.

Comment: You could turn the list of words into a regexp like `word1|word2|word3|...`. Then do a regexp match.

Comment: @pilchard definitely most of these change will improve the avg complexity, but the algorithm will still be O(m*n), where m is the lgtnh of the string and n is the number of English words. I was looking for some clever solution to solve this, probably trees are needed for this.

Comment: @Barmar there are around 170k words in the english alphabet, not sure that a query such as this would be very efficient, it doesn't allow you to specify any optimization

Comment: @LucaReccia Ideally the regexp compiler will optimize it.

Comment: How long are your strings? If they're long enough and the contents are somewhat random, the probability that they contain English words approaches 100%. Do you need to identify specifically which words they contain?

Comment: Strings vary between 10 and 200 chars, they have very high entropy and include a big charset (not only letters). 

I've never seen any of the random strings contain a word, but in that remote case it would not be a big issue as there is still some tolerance to errors.

The reality here is there only a human (or probably and advanced AI) is able to determine if a string is relevant to my analysis or not, my goal here is to remove as much noise as possible to then allow a quick human check. (all this to say that if it happens an error like this, it's not a big deal)

Comment: Define "English words" depends on a lot of factors but it can range to over 1M actual words; not sure how many of those are > 3 characters. `I'm` a word?

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss as English words, I would say anything in the OED. I just checked and there are about 600K, my dictionary is kinda smaller, but that's not the point. I already have a dictionary and now need the most efficient way to structure this data to make the algorithm work.
"I'm" is definitely not a word XD

Comment: FWIW I just used over 2 dozen > 3 len right in that string ^^

Comment: On which one @MarkSchultheiss, this could be an issue XD

Comment: in that first comment I made that starts with "Define" (which has multiple words IN it all by itself)  "defin" is a valid English word as is "fine" for example

Answer (score 2):

Looping over a dictionary (which may contain hundreds of thousands of words) is not a good idea. As your string ranges 10-200 chars, iterating over every characters in the source string gives a better result of time complexity. And if you don't care about space complexity, there's a better approach:

1. Build an ahead-of-time special dictionary hashmap, this costs you `O(m)` (which `m` is the number of your dictionary words). The hashmap will be something like:

```js
// As object is hashmap-like in javascript
dictionaryMap = {
   'hom': 'e',
   'cat': '',
   'bot': 'tle',
   'gla': ['ss', 'cier'], // contains 'glass' and 'glacier'
};
```

2. Iterate over every characters in the source string and look for the word, that way, you have O(n) time for the iteration and O(1) for the lookup:

```js
for (i=0; i<n.length; i++) {
   lookupStr := n[i] + n[i+1] + n[i+2]; // <-- I know it's dump, just a sample :)))
   if (dictionaryMap.hasOwnProperty(lookupStr) {
      console.log(lookupStr + dictionaryMap[lookupStr])
      return 'hell yeah';
   }
}
```

3. As now you know that the source string has a high chance that it contains an English word larger than 3, you can apply dynamic programming, building a tree or change the dictionaryMap and do step 2 recursion if you want to look for an exact word:

```js
dictionaryMap = {
   'gla': 'ss|cier'
}
// Apply dynamic programming or memoization to find the longest common continuous subsequence...
```

OR

```js
// Change the map to be a tree-like structure
dictionaryMap = {
   'gla': {
      's': {'s': ''},
      'c': {'i': {'e': {'r': ''}}}
   }
// Continue doing Step 2... 
// Or build a tree yourself and search for the exact word
```

=> Total: `O(m) + O(n) + O(1) = O(m)` time complexity and `O(m)` or `O(m*longestWordCharacters)` space complexity

Comment: It would probably be worth it to prune (once) the dictionary and remove words containing other words: no need for "battlement" if "battle" already is a positive. Profit could be substantial.

Comment: Yes. Basically, the idea is to build "Trie" data structure and do a search over a trie.

Answer (score -3):

Huh? This is not a job for node.js but JavaScript!

What is node.js...

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Node.js

Onto the problem at hand...

An English word greater than 3 letters... but there are tens of THOUSANDS of them!

Do you have a text file with all these words included so that we can load them into an array to operate?

No? OK, in the meantime here's the best we've got...

```
const Valid=['home','boTTle','glasses','GodKnows'];

var S='y89nsdadhomea98qwoi'.toLowerCase(), Ok=false;

for(var i=0; i<Valid.length; i++){

 if(S.includes(Valid[i].toLowerCase())){Ok=true; break;}

}


if(Ok){

 // yeah the string is ok, what now?

}
```

Sorry I’ve had a few scotches and LMAO after reading your post. :)

Comment: Yeah of course I meant javascript. I specified nodejs and lambda only to give you a better idea of what environment I'm working in :)

That's the standard algorithm that I've already mentioned. Can be optimized. Overall complexity O(m*n)-ish.
I was hoping to find someone that could give me some pointers on more clever way to even further optimize this. I'm pretty sure if I create a tree instead of having a list there is a lot of room for improvement. But I didn't want to reinvent the wheel and I'm hoping to find someone that faced a similar problem. As per the dictionary: dictionary-en

Comment: I suggest you come join me for a drink while we listen to “My Life Is A Party” and don’t worry too much! :)

Comment: I can't argue with that, thanks for the invite XD

Comment: I’ll be in Rome in a couple of months for about 10 days from CY… probably never see you but I love all things Italian… forca Italia my friend! :)